# Calculate ExpandableList's ListItem height at runtime

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using an `BaseExpandableListAdapter` in one of my `ListAdapters`.

Requirement is to fetch the height of the Parent's `ListItem`.

I tried using below code in `getGroupView()`:

```
listItem.measure(0, 0);
totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
```

But totalHeight is returning 0.

So, how *& where* can I calculate the height?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a onPreDrawListener.

The Height is 0 because you are asking for its height while its not layouted yet, so you will have to wait for the layout.

this is roughly what your code should look like

```
convertView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                return false;
            }
    });
```